# List of titles - grouping and creating initials

Tags: jquery, list

I have an alphabetical list of titles.

```
<div class="list">    
  <div><a href="http://www.example.com/id-1333">Alien</a></div>
  <div><a href="...">Argo</a></div>
  <div><a href="...">Art</a></div>
  <div><a href="...">Ban</a></div>
  <div><a href="...">Bruin</a></div>
  ...
</div>
```

First, I need to create div containers for titles that begin with the same letter, like this:

```
<div class="list>
  <div class="group">
    <div><a href="...">Alien</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Argo</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Art</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div><a href="...">Ban</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Bruin</a></div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Second, I need to create initials for each literal group, like this:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="initial">A</div>
    <div><a href="...">Alien</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Argo</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Art</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="initial">B</div>
    <div><a href="...">Ban</a></div>
    <div><a href="...">Bruin</a></div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I need a jQuery script that will dynamically convert the list. Solution need to include a scenario where in `<a>` tag there will be some attributes.

Comment: Sure, gonna get on doing your work for you.

Comment: I apologize, I will put what I did as far and I will ask for more specific road block question.

Comment: @sydbeat: Jokes aside, if you aim for providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is far more likely that someone will be able to provide you with assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will do the job. It is flexible, meaning: works by moving elements. And it ends up with only one div list with the same class name (conversion).

```
// main container class name: "list"

function removeDuplicateCharacters(string) {
    return string
        .split('')
        .filter(function(item, pos, self) {
            return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
        })
        .join('');
}

var initialsList = "";

$("main").append("<div class='test'></div>");
$("main").append("<div class='list-new'></div>");

$( ".list > .title > a" ).each( function(){
    initialsList += $(this).text().charAt(0);
});

var numberOfTitles = initialsList.length;
initialsList = removeDuplicateCharacters(initialsList)

for (var i=0; i<initialsList.length; i++) {
    $(".list-new").append("<div class='group'><div class='initial'>" + initialsList.charAt(i) + "</div></div>")
    $(".list > .title > a").each( function(){
        if ( initialsList.charAt(i) == $(this).text().charAt(0) ) {
            $(".group:last").append($(this).parent());
        }
    });
}

$(".list").remove();
$(".list-new").toggleClass("list-new list");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, here I am assuming that your result will be displayed in a div containing class resultList

```
    var text = [];
    var object = {};
    $("div.list div a").each(function(i, ele){
        text.push($(this).text());
    });
    text.sort();
    $.map(text, function(val, i){
        var index = val[0].toUpperCase();
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(index)){
            object[index].push(val);
        }else{
            object[index] = [];
            object[index].push(val);
        }
    });
    for(var key in object){
        var html = '<div class="group"><div class="initial">'+key+'</div>';
        $(object[key]).each(function(i, ele){
            html += '<div><a>'+ele+'</a></div>';
        });
        html += '</div>';
        $("div.resultList").append(html);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. Although rewritting tags this way:
html += '<div><a>'+ele+'</a></div>'
doesn't give me option to have actually real links.

Comment: Man you can use your URLS in the anchor tag as follows, if your url is stored in a JS variable url
html+='<div><a herf="'+url+'" target="">'+ele+'</a></div>'